# IndexOutOfBounds Exception for Card Shuffler

Tags: java, arraylist, random, card

I am trying to create a card shuffler method and I am currently having trouble with an IndexOutOfBounds exception.  I can't seem to understand why it is erroring out even after working through the code.

```
public static ArrayList<Card> shuffle(ArrayList<Card> currDeck) {
        var newDeck = new ArrayList<Card>();
        int length = currDeck.size();
        Random rand = new Random();
        int counter = 0;

        while (length != 0) {
            int index = rand.nextInt(length - 1);
            newDeck.set(counter, currDeck.get(index));
            currDeck.remove(currDeck.get(index));
            length --;
            counter ++;
        }


        return newDeck;
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: So, which line and with which values is triggering the error? Have you checked that `counter` never holds a value greater than the size of the deck?

Comment: Why don't you use `Collections.shuffle(currDeck);`?

Comment: You should be using `newDeck.add` instead of `newDeck.set`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`newDeck` starts out as an empty list - calling `set` on any index in it will produce an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` as there is no such index.

The good news is that you don't need all this code - you could just use [`Collections.shuffle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-):

```java
public static List<Card> shuffle(List<Card> currDeck) {
    List<Card> newDeck = new ArrayList<>(currDeck);
    Collections.shuffle(newDeck);
    return newDeck;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *debug* or *try-catch* in such error cases.

This is how you need to edit your index value assignment:

```
int index = rand.nextInt(length);
```

And you should add the cards to the new list as follows:

```
 newDeck.add(currDeck.get(index));
```

Except those...

You can only use `java.util.Collections.shuffle()` collections class method -> [Example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/collections-shuffle-java-examples/)

Good luck :)